# Why do we assign values to arguments in code, when its going to change depending on the users input?

Tags: javascript, arguments

I'm in the process of learning javascript.

I can't seem to understand something. As I have been learning, I have been told to plug in values for arguments as so:

```
function sayThanks(name) {
  console.log('Thank you for your purchase '+ name +'! We appreciate your business.');
}

sayThanks('Cole');
```

This will obviously print the statement to the console with 'Cole' being the argument.

But why would we assign 'Cole' as the argument when there will be multiple users with different names? Would you create a whole different function that inserts the persons name as the argument?

Comment: Usually, you write a function to perform certain task any number of times and 
 whenever you want, with different inputs. In the example above your wrote  function "sayThanks" to print the given input in console.  So you can invoke this function with any input(argument) which is a string.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would just *call* the function again with a new argument, no need to *redefine* the function again:

```js
function sayThanks(name) {
  console.log('Thank you for your purchase ' + name + '! We appreciate your business.');
}

sayThanks('Cole');
sayThanks('John');
sayThanks('Foo');
```

Comment: That makes sense. But how can you call the function for every single persons name who makes a purchase on this 'site'?

Comment: Impossible to say without knowing what exactly the site's code is, but perhaps when a purchase is made, retrieve the name of the purchaser, and then call the function with that name.

Answer (score 0):

If I might presume the nature of your incomprehension, it seems like you don't credit the function `sayThanks` with the ability to take more than one distinct argument; in this case, 'Cole'. Which implies that you think that you cannot then subsequently call `sayThanks('John')`. Which you absolutely can.

Think of `sayThanks` as a **template** of an action. Arguments are a way of inserting information (in your case, a name), into that template. This then allows the template to be used multiple times with *different* information (arguments).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do understand that I can subsequently call sayThanks() as many times as I want. Here's what I'm trying to get at - take this example for instance..      A random person, who we do not know the name of, goes to our 'site' and purchases one of our items. After said person purchases the product our code delivers the thank you message that is tailored to the purchaser's name. But, we do not know the name of the purchaser.. so ultimately my question is: why would we call sayThanks() hundreds of times with different arguments hoping the users name is one of our arguments?

Comment: You would not. Just like you wouldn't try to randomly guess someone's name on first meeting. You ask for the person's name, remember it, then repeat it when appropriate. In the context of a website, obviously you'll need to ask for the user's name at some point and record it (possibly in a cookie if you're not asking them to log in).

Practically though, it would be very unlikely that you wouldn't know the name of the purchaser. Digital purchases generally involve authorization, you would almost certainly gain their first name during the interaction.